# Struggling to switch to root user with Ansible

Tags: ansible

I'm a beginner with Ansible, and I need to run some basic tasks on a remote server.

The procedure is as follows:

- I log as some user (osadmin)
- I run `su -` to become root
- I then do the tasks I need to.

So, I wrote my playbook as follows:

```
---
- name: Some tasks
  become: yes
  become_user: root
  # become_method: su // Also tried with that.
  template: src=repo.j2 dest=/etc/yum.repos.d/test.repo owner=root group=root
  register: copy
```

Also, I have the following in `vars/main.yml`:

```
ansible_user: osadmin
ansible_password: password1
ansible_become_password: password2
[ some other values ]
```

However, when running my tasks, Ansible / the hosts returns me the following:

> "Incorrect sudo password"

While I'm sure I gave it the right password. So, I guess I'm not doing this correctly.

What would be the correct way to switch to root via `su`?

Thank you in advance

Comment: to become user root you need to provide the password of your root user, which is not the best option. Instead you could use your `osadmin` user if he has root privileges.

Comment: the root's password is provided with `ansible_become_password`, but somehow it says that the password isn't good

Comment: anyway the recommended way is to use your user on the machine if you have root privileges so you can omit the `become_user` all together

Comment: the user I'm trying to log with hasn't the root privileges, but can "log" as root itself by doing `su -`. I saw the recommended way, but somehow Ansible doesn't allow me to do so..

Comment: @Jaeger Could you please provide the folder structure?

Answer (score 0):

From your question, I see that variable values are stored in `vars/main.yml`. Instead have the variables inside `group_vars/all.yml` and uncomment `# become_method: su`.

Modified code

```
---
- name: Some tasks
  become: yes
  become_user: root
  become_method: su // Also tried with that.
  template: src=repo.j2 dest=/etc/yum.repos.d/test.repo owner=root group=root
  register: copy
```

have variables in `group_vars/all.yml`

```
ansible_user: osadmin
ansible_password: password1
ansible_become_password: password2
[ some other values ]
```

I tried this and it works for me.